# regex and postico

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have the following regex rules for my a text input in my app:

```
.replace(/ '/g, '')
.replace(/' /g, '')
.replace(/'/g, "''")
.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ')
.trim();
```

However, the string `Lincoln's Inn Lunch Waiter` will get sent to my backend as `{ role: 'Lincoln\'s Inn Lunch Waiter'}`
Anyone has any ideea how I can transform this into the original string, because it's causing some errors( my back-end is node )

Comment: Are you sure it's sent to the backend as `Lincoln\'s Inn Lunch Waiter`? This seems like the printed string representation, while the actual content is likely `Lincoln's Inn Lunch Waiter`.

Comment: @VLAZ that's what i get when i console log. but it doesn't work as intended, but if i change in my app the function that parses the data and i hardcode it as "Lincoln's Inn Lunch Waiter" it'll work whatsoever!

Comment: What are you even sending to the backend? Is it JSON? Is it *valid* JSON? I have trouble understanding why you get the output you do and how would it cause an error.

Comment: I'm asking the backend for this string. If this string matches do something, but it'll never match because it sends me that instead of the actual name. I tried to JSON.Stringify to no avail.

Comment: I'm basically querying. But it'll never return somethings because i ask for the normal string not the one i get.

Comment: running what you posted gave me a different output ( https://jsfiddle.net/8ba7f2pg/ ), it's : `Lincoln''s Inn Lunch Waiter` ( notice the `''` ) that could be your problem